# Variable is not nil but code thinks it's nil

Tags: ios, swift

I have a class that implements a protocol in order to add 3 variables. I specifically set the image variable, debugger show that the variable exist, but in code when I print it it shows nil, my `if let` statement also thinks the variable is nil.

```
@objc protocol DashboardItem {

    var title: String { get }
    var detail: String { get }
    optional var image: UIImage { get }

}

class StaticDashboardItem: DashboardItem {

    var title: String
    var detail: String
    var image: UIImage?

    init(title: String, detail: String, image: UIImage) {
        self.title = title
        self.detail = detail
        self.image = image
    }

}
```

EDIT: New screenshot[image]

Logs

```
nil
2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `StaticDashboardItem` does not fully implement your `DashboardItem` protocol. It conforms to it but does not implement the `var image: UIImage { get }` variable, which he has every right not to implement because this conformance is `optional`. So your `StaticDashboardItem` does not have any property/variable `image` **that is coming from that protocol**.

BUT, instead, you have added another, **completely unrelated** property `var image: UIImage?` to your `StaticDashboardItem`, and you unfortunately gave it the same named, hence your confusion. But that property `image` on your `StaticDashboardItem` is not the same as the one from your `DashboardItem` protocol and that's where your confusion comes from.

- If that `var image: UIImage?` from your `StaticDashboardItem` is intended to be the implementation of that non-mandatory `image` property from your protocol then the types must match, so that property from your `StaticDashboardItem` must be of type `UIImage`, not `UIImage?`.
- If that `var image: UIImage?` from your `StaticDashboardItem` is intended to be a completely different property unrelated to your protocol, then you better use a different name to avoid confusion.

---

[EDIT] Now that you've updated your question to show more code that confirms my assumptions. As your local `dashboardItem` parameter in your `configure` method is declared as a `DashboardItem` (so, the protocol), then `dashboardItem.image` refers to the protocol's property (as that code doesn't know about `StaticDashboardItem` of course, it only know the protocol), which in your case does not exist (you have no property named `image` of type `UIImage` in that `dashboardItem` you're introspecting) explaining that `println` result `nil` and that  `else` branch being executed, that's all to be expected given your code.

The only thing that misleads you is the debugger tooltip that *also* shows you avery other properties of the object being inspected, even properties not limited to the ones from your `DashboardItem` protocol type, so including that `image: UIImage?` property and any other coming from the `StaticDashboardItem` real type of your object.

Comment: Yes, this is why I was prompting him in my comment exchange to show how `dashboardItem` was declared. Now we know that (as I suspected) it is a DashboardItem, so the `image` property in his code is the (optional) _protocol_ `image` property, not the (Optional) instance property.

Comment: Yup, and that totally makes sense, so no Swift bug here, everything is entirely logical.

Comment: Plus he's going to need to take account of the fact that an optional protocol member is itself wrapped in an Optional. That is why he is getting "nil"; this is _that_ Optional, and it is reporting "this optional member is not implemented." Even if it _were_ implemented, he'd need to unwrap it to get at the image. And if he rewrites the optional member as an Optional, it will be _double-wrapped_. My book talks about this: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#SECoptionalProtocol

Comment: Aaaaah it makes sense, the requirement is UIImage, what I implemented is an Optional, and no compile errors since it's an optional protocol. Thanks to both answers

Answer (score 1):

You are being misled by the way the debugger works. In your screen shot, we are paused *before* the variable whose value you are examining. Thus, your tool tip showing the value of `dashboardItem` is not necessarily accurate. The value of `dashboardItem` is valid for lines *before* the line where we are paused, not for lines *after* the line where we are paused.

Comment: it says nil, look at the result of the println in debugger. Also if let goes to the else section

Comment: Then it's nil. What's the problem?

Comment: Debugger shows Some on optional, so it shouldn't be nil

Comment: But you are being misled by the debugger. Believe the `println`.

Comment: But the problem is I know that I set the value of image, my code goes through the initializer, initializer doesn't set the image parameter as an optional, so if a nil image was passed to initializer it would cause a crash. I have a feeling that this is somehow related to the protocol

Comment: Interesting. Then why is `image` declared as an Optional at all?

Comment: You are not confused between the notion of an Optional (a type) and an optional protocol member, are you?

Comment: It's optional because there is another initializer that takes an imageUrl instead of image, which is not getting called in this case. and no I do know the difference between the two optionals

Comment: Okay, but you see, now it turns out that there's a lot of other stuff that might be important, which you are claiming (in your comments) but not showing (in your question). How do I know how this `dashboardItem` got initialized? You are not showing that, so I have no faith in your claims. I have faith in the `println` statement! And so should you. That is what my answer is telling you. If it's nil, it's nil - no matter what the tooltip seems to show. Now you need to figure out why.

Comment: Updated the question with a better screenshot, I really think this is bug in swift

Comment: Aha. So `dashboardItem` is declared as a DashboardItem (the protocol). Just as I thought: you've confused yourself with the "optional" declaration of the `image` property in DashboardItem. The bug is in your code (and your understanding of how optional protocol members work), not in Swift. This is what I was getting at earlier when I suggested you might be confused about optional protocol members.